# how to convert jpeg byte array to bitmap byte array using visual studio C++

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio-2013

I've processed a jpeg byte array from a camera. Now I need to convert this jpeg byte array to bitmap byte array using visual studio C++

Comment: I think you need to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask sir.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a library for that. E.g. [jpeg-compressor](https://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/). Using jpeg-compressor, "conversion" to bitmap is straightforward:

```
#include "jpeg-compressor/jpgd.h"

int width = 0, height = 0, actual_comps = 0;
jpgd::decompress_jpeg_image_from_memory(
    static_cast<unsigned char*>(myJPEGdata), myJPEGdataLength,
    &width, &height, &actual_comps, 3 );
```